# Is there a (better) shorthand for TypeScript's string enums or object literals?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, enums

TypeScript enums look like this:

```js
enum Direction {
  Up = "Up",
  Down = "Down",
  Left = "Left",
  Right = "Right"
}
```

Enum declarations like these seem to me like unnecessary work. Especially with the DRY principle in mind. Isn't there a shorthand for declarations like this so that I don't need to repeat the values when they are equal to the keys? Sure, I could use numeric enums but they have that disadvantage that during debugging no meaningful values are present.

For example like the object literal shorthand from ES6:

```js
firstname = 'firstname';
lastname = 'lastname';

fullname = {
  firstname,
  lastname
}
```

But even with this shorthand definition I still need to write for example `firstname` three times. Isn't there an easier way?

Would be nice if something like this would work:

```js
// for enums:
string_enum Direction {
  Up,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right
}

// for object literals:
fullname: {
  'firstname',
  'lastname'
}
```

Comment: You can try using a type insted of enum, like type DirectionType = "up" | "down" | "left" | "right"

Comment: @DhanukaPerera I would like to use the values then like so `goTo(Direction.Left)`. This wouldn't be possible with a type, right?

Comment: @DhanukaPerera I want VSCode to be able to autocomplete the directions

Comment: You could do something like `Direction[Direction.Up] // "Up"`, but that feels a little hacky imo :P

Comment: @NickParsons yes... again, writing the same word twice is kinda anti DRY, right?

Comment: @winklerrr IDEs can complete such (literal union) types as well when using them for arguments etc as long as those are typed properly.

Comment: @winklerrr you should [try it out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgJwgY2HA9gOygXigIgFUx8oAfAmdAd01IvwBkIAzYeggJTgHMALdgG4AUMiwBnYFGQBXBI3TIAhmiy4oAbygAPAFxQADABooIfQagBfEWMySoPdABV06gBQATRClWZ98JFQMTABKXAA+TWEoGOk5BWVfADptKABqPC1icxMqWhyoZjZ9AFoARhNufmB9MqsAbS9A3wBdEVi4+UUVYKSQdMyobKgK2Bo-KHKTIprDSt4Bcwamn2C24WthRxc3fHwQwSgAeiOoAB4SkqgwGSlZBHF0BCgAIwhgaggIbABHGXRgBBxFAlJgPFA+HA7sAEAAbEriMBKZAQIA) and see if that works for you.  If so, someone should write it up as an answer.

Comment: One of the drawbacks of using `or` types is that you can't easily refactor the value of a constant.

Comment: If you use numeric enums you can get useful debugging in js if you don't use `const enum`. Look at the generated js from [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAhlUG8AWBLANAGwPYHcC+AUARsAC5QBGAXHALywB0qQA).

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly what you were asking for; it doesn't create a true enum but it does remove the duplication and it gives you enum-like behavior. We wrote this before real string enums were available and have mostly stopped using this since the duplication in string enums may not be pretty but it seldom causes bugs.

```
/**
 * This creates a string enum.  Use like so:
 *     const Ab = strEnum(['a', 'b']);
 *     type AbKeys = keyof typeof Ab;
 * @param keys keys in the enum
 * @returns enum object
 */
export function createStringEnum<T extends string>(keys: T[]): {[K in T]: K} {
    return keys.reduce((res, key) => {
        res[key] = key;
        return res;
    }, Object.create(null));
}
```

In the above case, AbKeys is the type you can use when taking in one of those object. Note that this is not a true enum because you can pass the strings in and the compiler will be happy, which would not be the case with enums

**Example**

```
const Ab = createStringEnum(['a', 'b']);
type AbKeys = keyof typeof Ab;
function choose(key: AbKeys) {
  if (key === Ab.a) {
    return 'A'
  }
  return 'B';
}
// Type error
console.log(Ab.c);
// OK
console.log(choose(Ab.b));
// A true string enum wouldn't allow this
console.log(choose('a'));
// At least, it does't allow this...
function test (a: string)  {
  console.log(choose(a));
}
```

See example on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgVAFgSwM7QMYCcCmBDAFx3T2lQK2QDsBzaHKgVwFsA6aaAVVR2gBtkAa16oA9gC4osDjIyiq5aAEEARtAC8ZCgFEmzABQBtAOR5jAGmjGVxgLoBKANxS4M6AQCeAB16qA0jge6JrCHqIAZu7eOBHKKs4wcAACXnhYeMzQoejZ0NTuiLwMLC7QSbgEjFgK9HrQoioAVjgYBC7AUDgAHl6iWATQ4YxUrcjymLiEOADKFNQ0uiwAPPD0XURUACbo5JS0AHz62eIIhg4nAN6GfnlUCLYnfgC+0BdSMhVVd9msuJuMGBw+n0uFQllC9g0+1e7zcHFBhlCtg0WUCCThHxwlWq0FB6JkT0sAHkmi0CKxsPgiPomHw+PYnFAnlAoHIFANVCjKVNZnsFnojKYLFYbA4Ep4fHEAkEUaFYhKYpFVAkhiMCGM7hhEKJRDwjoETv5AqhIW8YHlIvqPBp1JpVKw8KbYbisV8rEpjO9mebPjjjAAhYwJb3AYAIaL0LBYPqs+RiPg4Vh8UQ0fT2jCMyCh6BEvyxhSiBNJlP6LU6vX2lQMhLZpTuLCMERzWi1FjQADuokYfE2VGMAzwdNE7YKaHz8cTydTZd1QKF1agtYGCbw5EsyAGm1ExH70EHyZHBBQqFYp6gqtG4yIin0eBOu3mkJh5rZE+L0+1s9vC8g3qAA)

Comment: Seems to me like a pretty complex solution for such a "simple" problem... When anyone else (or I in a few weeks) is looking at these "string enums" they have to go through all the code first to understand what's going on. Please don't get me wrong, I think you have provided a nice and I also guess functioning solution but the readability of that code compared to a simple enum where the values match the keys (even if that violates the DRY principle) seems to be much lower.

Comment: @winklerrr Pretty complex? All the 5 lines of code? I tried to make it pretty obvious that we used this before string enums were available and pointed out some of its flaws already. We just use string enums instead nowadays, I just wanted to put this out here since you were interested and I believe this is the closest you will get.

Answer (score 1):

Since TypeScript 3.4, you can use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

While not an enum, I'm fond of using an array like so:

```
const DIRECTIONS = ["Up", "Down", "Left", "Right"] as const
type Direction = typeof DIRECTIONS[number]
function goTo(direction: Direction) {
  // ...
}

goTo(" // with that open quote, you would see a list of the string literals
```

You don't get the benefit of having an object as a "representative" to access the strings (e.g., `Direction.Up`), but with any modern IDE config for TypeScript, you will get robust auto completion and type coverage.

Answer (score -2):

```
enum Directions {
    "LEFT",
    "RIGHT",
    "UP",
    "DOWN",
}

const goTo = (direction: Directions) => {
    // use Directions[direction] to get the value.
    // Otherwise you get only the index.
    console.log("my direction is ", Directions[direction]);

    // check directions
    if (Directions[direction] === Directions[Directions.LEFT]) {
        console.log("I go left...");
    }

   // when check directions not madary to extract that value.
   if (direction === Directions.LEFT) {
      console.log("I go left...");
   }


};

goTo(Directions.LEFT);
```

Comment: Produces a numeric enum when the original question asked for a string enum or object with string-valued properties.